# Flex - new ClassFactory() vs Fully Qualified Name

Tags: apache-flex, fully-qualified-naming

When assigning the itemrenderer of an object it is better to use a fully qualified name string or use ClassFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itemRenderer` is typed as IFactory, so ideally it should be a ClassFactory.  But it seems that the compiler can figure out what you mean if you just use the fully qualified name, and the generated and compiled actionscript will use IFactory no matter what I'm guessing.  I use the string just so I don't have to import ClassFactory and IFactory.  If I use `itemRendererFunction` though, I use ClassFactory.

Answer (score 4):

**[Flex-Builder specific]** Personally I use a class factory as makes it possible for me to `control-click` the Class name of my item renderer and go straight to that class to view the code.  Saves a bit of time.

This alone makes the class factory method "better"...for me at least.